# Wordpress JQuery not running for plugins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

No matter what I seem to do, JQuery will not run properly on my wordpress site!

*Note - This is my first wordpress website*

I have tried what seems to be everything now but I can't get jQuery to properly run on my wordpress website.

**I have tried removing the default wordpress jquery and running my own by using**

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', false, '3.3.1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

But this returns the following errors

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function / jquery-3.3.1.min.js
>   Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function / front-end-deps.js

**I have tried to load jquery first before both my header and footer scripts**

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
include(locate_template('inc/layout/header-layout.php'));
wp_head();
```

This removes the `jQuery.ajax is not a function` error, but then any plugin I install cannot find jquery and returns errors like

> jQuery is not defined

**I have manually called jquery into `wp_enqueue_script()` where possible, such as

```
wp_enqueue_script('my_script_name', array('jquery'));
```

Which tends to fix it, but this option is not available for all plugins.

**I have completely removed all of my manual jQuery calls and tried allowing wordpress to do it by default**

This doesn't throw any immediate errors, until a plugin tries to use Jquery, then I get

> Uncaught TypeError JQuery.ajax is not a function

Surely the way that wordpress includes Jquery should make it accessible to the entire site?

*Few things to note, as I said this is my first wordpress site so im not sure if these are normal or not*

- When I inspect the website and view the website sources, there is no jquery. I'm assuming that it is compiled and added into the 'scripts.js' file? As thats the only javascript file my site is running.
- When I run `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`, it doesn't actually do anything to the code. For example, if I run it in the header, and then check the source code, it doesn't add in jquery or anything. Am I wrong in thinking that `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` should add JQuery in to the code?
- Some of the plugins I am using that cannot find jQuery are NinjaForms and SB Instagram (NinjaForms doesnt display any errors until i try to submit a form, i then recieve `jQuery.ajax is not a function`)

I have searched all over the internet and tried most of what I have found, so as far as i'm aware this isn't a duplicate question!

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can trouble shoot this and fix it?

*Edit*

I can get it so that JQuery loads, is viewable in the source and doesn't error, but then as soon as a plugin tries to access it, it throws the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: just using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` is not proper way. you should to use action `wp_enqueue_scripts` for adding your scripts to wordpress queue

Comment: also, `jquery` loads in the wordpress by default. if you didn't removed it, then check cache/plugins/themes which may deactivated it

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan can you explain what you mean by cache/plugins/themes? Is this a file? A wordpress setting?

Comment: by default( fresh wordpress installation without 3-rd part plugins and themes ) loads `jquery` library. If it isn't on your website, then it may be removed handly/from some plugin/theme functions. I can't guess what theme/plugins contain your website. but try to deactivate all plugins, and switch to some default theme( like twentyseventeen ). then you'll see `jquery` on your pages

Comment: Maybe post a list of the plugins you are using?

Comment: I have tried to deactivate all plugins and it still can't find jquery

Comment: so, the problem is with your theme. do you added some code to deactivate `jquery` ?

Comment: I have tried to change the theme, and still nothing? Even if i manually add ` <script src="wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` to the `header.php` file in my theme, my plugins still can't find jquery. It showns in the source, and jquery is definitely there, but the plugins just ignore it.

Comment: what you mean with `ignore` ?

Comment: As in, jquery is being loaded at the top of my page, and i can confirm its there, but the plugins say its not there, they just ignore it.

Comment: I can confirm it is an issue with my theme, but what is the best way to trace it?

Answer (score 1):

So a few things, you don't manually have to enqueue jquery as you can pass it as a parameter to your other queries.  If you look at the example below the wp_enqueue_script function has 3 parameters. ('file name', 'directory', 'array of scripts to be loaded before this one').

`wp_enqueue_script('semantic.min.js', '/wp-content/plugins/ct-plugin/js/semantic.min.js', array('jquery'));`

The other thing is that in wordpress you cannot use the `$` shorthand for jQuery you must type out `jQuery()`, in your script for it to load properly.  Maybe if you can provide some context of the script you are trying to run it would help us diagnose better.

My last thought is that when the plugin is being loaded you aren't calling a function to load these enqueue your values.  See the following code below on how to hook into the enqueue process on wordpress to load your own scripts in.

`//Create the action to enqueue the admin scripts
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');`

Resource for how to use wp_enqueue_script found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_amazing_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-great-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/js/your-amazing-jquery.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.1', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_amazing_scripts');
```

Comment: This directory isn't right, my site is trying to fetch `http://mywebsite.local/wp-content/plugins/C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mywebsite/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: In the `functions.php` file of my theme. I changed the code to `wp_enqueue_script('my-great-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  .'/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.1', true);` and it found the file, but my plugins still ignore it.

Comment: Are you using jQuery inside one of your plugin's or inside your theme?

If you need jQuery to be loaded by your plugin please check this example: https://github.com/brabia/WordPress-Plugins/tree/master/plug-and-play/trunk/bPress

Here a working example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/plug-and-play/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

in your wp-config.php file.

However this may act more like a debugging tool in order to help you isolate the issue not 'solve' it.
I think your issue is caused by a plugin. Please disable ALL plugins and remove any method where you manually added jQuery in your code then try again.

Comment: This was already in my wp-config.php file, didn't do anything. I have tried disabling all plugins and still nothing.